# What do I have to install to update MOSS?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, patch-management, update

I found this great blog post on SharePoint patches:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sowmyancs/archive/2008/09/24/all-available-sharepoint-service-packs-patches-and-related-information.aspx

My question is do I have to install them all in order? or do the later ones include the earlier ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [SharePoint Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/Default.aspx). They post lots of good information, including info about updating your server. [Here is there latest one](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/10/29/october-2009-cumulative-update-packages-for-sharepoint-server-2007-and-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx), the will get a fully unpatched server up to the October 2009 cumulative update. In short, install WSS SP2, MOSS SP2, WSS Oct 2009 CU, MOSS Oct 2009 CU, run the technology & configuration wizard, all in that order.